# Simplify launching an EC2 instance with a given configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there any way to create a link or "saved profile" for launching an EC2 instance with a given configuration?

I'm aware of the mechanism where you can create a link to launch a given AMI, i.e.  http://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#launchAmi=ami-XXXXXX.  However, there are still a lot of configuration steps left (instance type, security group, etc).

Is there anyway to automate this process, in such a way that it can be launched by an arbitrary Amazon account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/).

The idea is that you create a JSON "template" document that describes the resources (EC2 instance, EBS volumnes, security groups, RDS services, etc) for a given "stack". The JSON document can be more-or-less independent of a specific account. You can also specify configuration prompts (which region to launch in, etc) to collect additional information from whomever is actually launching the stack.

From the AWS CloudFormation page:

> Create additional stacks (if needed) by simply using existing
>   templates you’ve created, choosing from one of our sample templates,
>   or creating a new one from scratch. Since templates are text files
>   that can be created and managed outside of CloudFormation, you can
>   share them easily through email, source control repositories, or
>   services such as Amazon S3.

Comment: Good call, I hadn't thought of this.